# how to reset code coverage highlight in intelij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-coverage

just configured Intelij-idea 2016-1 to highlight covered and non-covered lines of code (after running unit tests with coverage). so i can see the uncovered lines and just want to continue coding but the annoying colors won't go off without switching the theme (to default or Darcula) or even opening and closing the project.
is there any solution with less pain?!

Comment: As of 2023 (IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.4) the option to hide the coverage data in the editor has been moved to the "Run" menu (Run -> Hide coverage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really simple actually. After you run your tests with coverage, you'll probably get a new pane (named Coverage) that shows coverage statistic per package. On the left hand side of that pane there's a red X button, clicking on that will hide all Coverage related highlighting.

Comment: No problem, definitely not the most intuitive UI :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check the 'Code Coverage' settings within the 'Run/Debug Configuration' for your test. It seems record details of specific packages to include/exclude from code coverage. It might be the source of your issue.

Comment: i have no problem with included/excluded, they are ok, coverage reports and colors are very informative, but after some minutes staring at them i'm finished, just want the theme before running tests (without highlighted colors that make me blind)

Answer (score -1):

In current versions (2019.1) it is in the *Analyze* menu -> *hide coverage*.